# var for private vs underscope inside function constructor

Tags: javascript, oop

What is the best way to imitate private variables?

Use var

```
var varName;
```

or use (just make a rule that all variables, which start from "_" will be private).

```
this._varName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This completely depends on your use case. Using `var varName` gives you true private variables, but they can only be accessed inside the constructor function and not in member functions. If this is okay, use this.

However if you need to use the variable inside member functions, the only option is to use a syntax rule to say a variable is private or not, in this case `this._varName` helps

Comment: My constructor consists all functions which i use. I don't use prototyping way.

Comment: then, `var varName` would be the best option for you